# Android youtube player load video method calls the onvideo ended instead of loading the video

Tags: android, youtube-api

Min_sdk = 11
I have integrated  YouTube player view in one of the screens in my app and the first video starts playing perfectly by calling all the call back listener methods but when I try to load video it doesn't work instead calls the onvideo ended method without playing the video.

I get the YouTube player in the variable youtubeplayer1 in the initialize method as shown in the code below

```
youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new MHPlaybackEventListener());
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new MHPlayerStateChangeListener());
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_url);
        youTubePlayer1 = youTubePlayer;
```

I use the variable to pause and play videos and try to load videos as shown below

```
  if(youTubePlayer1!=null)
            {
                youTubePlayer1.cueVideo(video_url);
            }
```

MHPlayerstatechangedlistener

```
    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        System.out.println("onAdStarted PlayerStateChangeListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onAdStarted video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        System.out.println("onError PlayerStateChangeListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onError video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        System.out.println("onLoaded PlayerStateChangeListener... (starting play and timer)"+" is started="+isStarted);
            youTubePlayer1.play();

        startTimer(timeRemaining);
        System.out.println("onLoaded PlayerStateChangeListener... (end)"+" is started="+isStarted);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        System.out.println("onLoading PlayerStateChangeListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //  library.messageBox("Hello");
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onLoading video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        System.out.println("onVideoEnded PlayerStateChangeListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onVideoEnded video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //  startTimer(1); // we are displaying time-1,
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        System.out.println("onVideoStarted PlayerStateChangeListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onVideoStarted video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

MHPlaybackEventListener

```
    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        System.out.println("onBuffering PlaybackEventListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onBuffering video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        // TODO: pause the timer as well
        System.out.println("onPaused PlaybackEventListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //System.out.println("");
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onPaused video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isStarted =false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        System.out.println("onPlaying PlaybackEventListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onPlaying video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        isStarted =true;
                }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        System.out.println("onSeekTo PlaybackEventListener..."+" is started="+isStarted);
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onSeekTo video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        // TODO: stop the timer as well
        isStarted =false;
    }
}
```

I tried load video method,intialise the youtube player view again but nothing worked. It all calls only the onvideoended method

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the listener also ?

Comment: yep code updated

Comment: Try using the sample provided by Google: [Simple PlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) and [Simple PlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment), this show how po play a video in `PlayerView` or `PlayerFragment`. This will help you to get familiar on how to use the YouTube Android Player API then apply this to your application. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah i understand youtubeplayerview but i don't understand why youtubeplayer is not loading the video?

Comment: So let me get you right...As far as I know, if you use `cueVideo()` it will load the video but will wait for user to play it. In the case of `loadvideo()` method, the player starts automatically. In your case, using `cueVide()` calls onVideoEnded ? Or what's exactly the scenario ?

Comment: When the user selects the video from the list, it starts new activity where the youtube player view is initialized and cuevVideo() method is called in oninitialisationsuccess() method. The video loads and plays successfully. After the video is finished playing, i wanted to load the next video in the same player view instead of initializing the player view again but in my case, after load video or cue video method is called, immediately onstopped() method and onvideoended() method is called instead of playing the video. This the problem i am facing now.